# With angular.js using ui-router, how to only reload one view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a fairly simple todo app using angular.js for which I am using the ui-router library. I looked through the ui-router example on github (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/master/sample) but was unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. In my app I have a sidebar navigation view (with the list of things todo) and a content view (which displays the todo item's details when clicked). The problem I have is that when I navigate to /todo/exampleItem the content view updates and the navigation panel is reloaded as well. This doesn't effect the functionality of the app but I would like to avoid the navigation panel flickering each time you click on an item.

Here is my code to handle the state changes:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('todo', {
        url: "/todo", 
        views: {
            "navPanel": {
                templateUrl: "./navPanel.html",
                controller: 'PanelController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('todo/:item', {
        url: "/todo/:item", 
        views: {
            "PanelView": {
                templateUrl: "./navPanel.html",
                controller: 'PanelController'
            },
            "ContentView": {
                templateUrl: "./content.html",
                controller: 'ContentController'
            }
        }
    })

});
```

In my index.html my views are set up as follows:

```
  <div class="column" data-ui-view="PanelView"></div>
  <div class="column" data-ui-view="ContentView"></div>
```

Is there some way I can stop the navPanel view from being reloaded each time a new item is clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the voted answer of that question [angularjs ui-router - how to build master state which is global across app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473952/angularjs-ui-router-how-to-build-master-state-which-is-global-across-app)

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('todo', {
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            "navPanel": {
                templateUrl: "./navPanel.html",
                controller: 'PanelController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('todo/:item', {
        url: "/todo/:item", 
        views: {
            "ContentView@": {
                templateUrl: "./content.html",
                controller: 'ContentController'
            }
        }
    })

}]);
```

Comment: When I add the abstract true line it makes my navPanel vanish. I think I must be missing something conceptually on how nested views work. I will keep researching and post back when I have a solution. Thanks for you help though!

Comment: Can you try changing `navPanel` to `PanelView` in the abstract state?

Comment: Wow, that was the issue, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. But when I use abstract:true, the console show me an error says : `Cannot transition to abstract state 'myState'`. How did you achieve to display correctly your grid and only reload the form when choose to edit an item?