# How can i keep the old content of an ui-view and change another when i trigger state transition ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view

I started for weeks to use **angularjs** and i found it very awsome !
i used also **ui-router** for multiple and nested views, here is my problem:
i have 2 states "**state1**" "**state2**" and 2 named ui-view "**viewA**" and "**viewB**" in my *index.html*.
When i go to "**state1**" i render *list.html* in "**viewA**" and "*edit.html*" in "**viewB**",
and when i go to "**state2**" i render "*create.html*" in "**viewA**", the problem is "**viewB**" becomes empty, i want the old content of "**viewB**" still displayed.
So how can i keep the old content of an *ui-view* when i trigger *state transition* ?
I hope that all this is very clear and thank you very much.

***index.html***

```
 <a ui-sref="state1">state1</a>
    <a ui-sref="state2">state2</a>

    <div ui-view ="viewA"> </div>
    <div ui-view ="viewB"> </div>
```

***module.config***

```
$stateProvider
         .state('state1', {

        views: {
            "viewA": { templateUrl: "views/nfl/list.html" },
            "viewB": { templateUrl: "views/leagues/edit.html" }
        }
    });
$stateProvider 
         .state('state2', {

        views: {
             "viewA": { templateUrl: "views/nfl/create.html" }

    }
});
```

Comment: Check out [this question][1] and see if that answers your problem. I think it might. 




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476694/with-angular-js-using-ui-router-how-to-only-reload-one-view?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

View is changed because it is a part of state.

I think you need to create abstract state #1 with viewB as edit, then create states: state #2 as state1.1 with viewA list.html and state #3 as state1.2 with viewA create.html - this way may help you.

(I didn't tested)